# Paper.js unable to import SVG properly

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs

I have the following SVG,

[image]

But when I import it with Paper.js it looks like this

[image]

My guess is that it is ignoring the `style="mix-blend-mode:soft-light` part of the markup.

Here is a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Shouldn't you be reporting that [here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues)?

Comment: @RobertLongson, I will do that once I am sure this is an issue and not because of something I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem comes from the fact that `Paper.js` doesn't support patterns (https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1696) and your SVG code relies on it.

Otherwise, `soft-light` blend mode should be supported, I you find a bug with it (try to reduce the reproduction case as much as possible), feel free to create an issue in `Paper.js` repository as suggested in the comment.